# Acessing WP functions in form submission handler

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I have a form which is embedded in a custom post type.

The form action points to a PHP file that sits in my mu-plugins directory:

```
<form action="http://www.foo.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/FormCode/formprocess.php">
```

This works fine; upon 'submit', this PHP file is invoked.

The problem I'm having is that `formprocess.php` doesn't seem to "see" core WP functions as in-scope.  For example, calling `wp_verify_nonce()` is throwing an HTTP 500 error.

I tried adding `require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-includes/pluggable.php');` and it is still not working.

What else can I do to assure that core WP files are available to my form handler?  Or, is there an entirely different approach I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing files within WP installation directly is a bad practice. While you *can* implement a custom core load routine, it is fragile and impossible to reliably ship in public plugins.

There are different approaches to form submission in WP. On of the most appropriate ones (if slightly underknown) is sending form to [`wp-admin/admin-post.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-post.php) and using hooks inside to attach processing logic.

Comment: Thanks, Rarst - you are 100% correct and I have used this method before, I had just forgotten about it.  Unfortunately for this particular case I was not able to get it to work -- I'm doing this via AJAX with `admin-ajax.php` -- and I could not get the function to be called based on the `wp_ajax_nopriv_` action firing.  I think it's because I am trapping the output buffer and making string substitutions, and it's screwing up the execution sequence.  Anyway I ended up using `require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );` in my handler function.  Ugly, but simple.